# ¿Como puedo mostrar el clientName dentro el formbuilder?

Tags: angular, angular5

```
export class UpdateUserComponent {

   registerForm: FormGroup;
   public users:Array<User> = [];
   public clientName: string;
   public password: string;

   constructor(
       private formBuilder: FormBuilder,
       private _userService:UserService,
   ) {}

  ngOnInit(){
    this._userService.edit(0).subscribe(res => {
      let users = <User[]>res;
      this.clientName = res.clientName;
      console.log(this.clientName);
  });

  this.registerForm.controls['clientName'].setValue(this.clientName);

    this.registerForm = this.formBuilder.group({
      'clientName': [this.clientName],
      'email': [''],
      'phone': [''],
      'password': ['']
    });
  }
}
```

Me sale que es `undefined` el `this.clientName` del `formBuilder`.

¿Como lo puedo hacer?

Gracias!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No muestras si tienes declarado this.clientName, pero como has comentado que estas usando formBuilder entiendo que no.

Para asignar un valor a un campo del formBuilder lo tienes que hacer de la siguiente manera:

```
this.registerForm .controls['nombreCampo'].setValue("ValorCampo");
```

Este es el código que tienes que tener:

```
this.registerForm = this.formBuilder.group({
  'clientName': [this.clientName],
  'email': [''],
  'phone': [''],
  'password': ['']
});

this._userService.edit(0).subscribe(res => {
  let users = <User[]>res;
  this.registerForm .controls['clientName'].setValue(res.clientName);
});
```

Saludos.

Comment: Me sale este error: ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'controls' of undefined

Comment: Puedes mostrar como te quedo el código? A ver la primera línea es como se tiene que hacer, me parece que lo copiaste tal cual y no es así. Voy a editar para que lo tengas más claro

Answer (score 1):

Debes asignarlo a los controles de tu `FormGroup`

```
this.registerForm.controls['clientName'].setValue(res.clientName);
```

Ademas cuando crees el `FormGroup` debes hacerlo asi:

```
this.formBuilder.group({
    clientName: new FormControl(''),
    email: new FormControl(''),
    phone: new FormControl(''),
    password: new FormControl('')
});
```

También te sugiero cambiar la creación de tu `FormGroup` en el `ngOnInit`

```
ngOnInit(){

    this.registerForm = this.formBuilder.group({
        clientName: new FormControl(''),
        email: new FormControl(''),
        phone: new FormControl(''),
        password: new FormControl('')
    });
}
```

Comment: Me funciono! Muchas gracias!